# postgresql different configuration for different tablespace

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm configuring new server with both SSD/HDD disk with ubuntu 18.04. I've installed system in SSD and created two different tablespaces one in ssd and one in hdd. I would like for configuration purposes put:

HDD

```
random_page_cost 4
effective_io_concurrency 2
```

SDD

```
random_page_cost 1.1
effective_io_concurrency 200
```

for each correct tablespace. Is it possible or are there some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for [ALTER TABLESPACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertablespace.html).

Since version 9.6, you can set "effective_io_concurrency" on a per-tablespace basis. You can do so for "random_page_cost" long before 9.6.

These changes have to be made inside the database itself. For discoverability purposes, I would also add a comment inside postgresql.conf near the global settings, saying that they have been tweaked per tablespace.  Otherwise, it is not very obvious that these changes have been made.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response. I'm thinking about what if i create a new cluster and divide the data between the two disks between the clusters one on port 5432 and the other one on 5433? I have to set one postgresql.conf file for "shared_buffers", "max_worker_processes", "max_parallel_workers", etc and modify the above "random_page_cost", "effective_io_concurrency" per cluster or as before for each tablestapce in cluster? Could it be better solution?

Comment: @isipostgresqluser  If the data is independent from each other, that would be fine.  But if you need to query the data together, then you would have to use something like postgres_fdw to do it.  postgres_fdw is a great tool, but nowhere near as efficient as having the data in the same database is.